# List View Webpart with Thumbnail View

Tags: web-part, list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part, picture-library

I have a Picture library and I use the default Thumbnails view. So I created a List View WebPart on the home page and the items are all messed up. Instead of showing in a nice and tidy grid, there are gaps between the items. After a while I discovered that this issue is present only in IE. Has anyone encountered this issue? And any pointers on how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot or image?

Comment: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/12/listviewwebpart.png/) - here you go. This is the list view webpart in question and actualy it is using a flat view (without folders) but the issue is the same. Another interesting thing is that i have another webpart of another library next to it and it shows ok.

Comment: Try to delete the webpart and recreate a new picture library webpart.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I tried that but with no success. I even recreated the view witch I use but the result was the same. And the error isn't even consistent. I've set an item limit of 30 and while the first 30 would have this issue, the next 30 would be ok and the next ones would be scattered again.

Comment: Have you tried a different view style? Also, do you have any customizations on the page or masterpage?

Comment: Well the masterpage is not changed. As for the page, I did some exerimenting, but later I reseted it to the site definition. Additionally I created a new page and tested the webpart there, no change.
I don't know if that's relevant but the folders in the library have unique permissions and do not inherit from the library. This is for preventing some users to read some of the content. But as administrator I can see all the folders.

Comment: Is the view "right to left" or "left to right" in the webpart layout?